# An Uncountable Subset of a Topological Space with a Countable Base $\Rightarrow$ M contains a limit point

Tags: general-topology

Please provide hints and not a direct answer as I would like to figure this out myself.

Prove that if $M$ is an uncountable subset of a topological space with a countable base, then some point of $M$ is a limit point of $M$

So far, If M has a countable base then there exits a countable everywhere dense subset $N \subset M$ such that $[N]=M$ $\Rightarrow$ $M$ contains all the limit points of $N$. The only way for our claim to be false is if N is made entirely of interior points $\Rightarrow$ N is open. Then $M$ is open is this a contradiction? Any hints on how to proceed would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: The topological space has the countable base, not $M$.  $M$ has a countable base doesn't really mean anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:  If $M$ doesn't have a limit point, then for each $x\in M$ take an open set $U_x$ with $U_x\cap M\setminus\{x\}=\emptyset$.  Then there is $B_x\in\mathcal B$ with $x\in B_x\subset U_x$, by the definition of a basis.

> But $x\ne y\implies B_x\ne B_y$.  This implies $M$ is countable.  Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $x \in M$ is not a limit point of $M$, then there is an open set $A_x$ in the given base such that $A_x \cap M = \{x\}$. If no point of $M$ is a limit point of $M$, what can you say about the sets $A_x$?